# How to add today's date to django templates

Tags: python, django, datetime, variables, django-templates

I researched how I could pass in a datetime object to my templates, but none of them seems to work. Here is the code for my view:

```
class LeadListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    # some other code
    today_date = datetime.date.today()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LeadListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['today_date'] = self.today_date
        return context
```

However, when I try to use the `today_date` in the template, it doesn't work. I am trying to use the `today_date` so that I might use it in an if statement to see if today's date is between two other datetime variables. Thanks a lot!

Some additional information on how the django template looks like:

```
{% if lead.class_start_date <= today_date and lead.class_end_date >= today_date %}
{% endif %}
```

Here, `class_start_date` and `class_end_date` are just part of the Lead model.

This is the full list view:

```
class LeadListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    tempalte_name = "leads/lead_list.html"
    context_object_name = "leads"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        # initial queryset of leads for the entire organisation
        if user.is_organisor:
            queryset = Lead.objects.filter(
                organisation=user.userprofile,
                agent__isnull=False
            )
        else:
            queryset = Lead.objects.filter(
                organisation=user.agent.organisation, 
                agent__isnull=False
            )
            #filter for the agent that is logged in
            queryset = queryset.filter(agent__user=user)
        return queryset
```

Comment: exactly how do you render this in the listview?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think there is a render for a class based generic view.

Comment: how does the template look like?

Comment: I editted it above for your reference.

Comment: if you try to filter data, you should do that in the view, since then you can filter at the *database* side, which is more efficient than filtering in the template.

Comment: Okay. Could you tell me how to do that? I have no idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230575/discussion-between-john-song-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to pass this to the context. Django already has a [**`{% now … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now).

You thus can render this with:

```
{% now 'DATE_FORMAT' %}
```

If you plan to *filter* however on the current day, you should filter in the view, since that will filter at the database level, which is more efficient:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class LeadListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Lead
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        today = now().date()
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            class_start_date__lte=today,
            class_end_date__gte=today
        )
```

Comment: What would I do if my query set looks like above?(I edited it into the question)

Comment: @JohnSOng: just add the filters to each of the querysets you construct.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.. queryset.filter(agent__user=user).filter(
            class_start_date__lte=today,
            class_end_date__gte=today
        )

Comment: @JohnSong: exactly *what* is not working.

Comment: Hey Willem, thanks a lot! I think there was some issue with my computer, but its working now. It originally poped out an error message, but its gone now. Again, thanks for your help. Appreciate it!